# How to make a path from variables

Tags: python, path, operating-system

```
 content = os.path.abspath("content")
for i in os.listdir(os.path.abspath("content")):
    path = str(i)
    bot.upload_photo(content "/" path, caption ="Technical Scripter Event 2019")
```

SO, I need to make something like this.The program makes the files from the folder variables and I need to connect the path to it.

Comment: `content "/" path`  -> `content + "/" + path` -> `os.path.join(content, path)`

Comment: You don't need `str(i)`, because `i` is already a string object.

Answer (score 2):

This line contains a syntax error:

```
bot.upload_photo(content "/" path, caption ="Technical Scripter Event 2019")
```

In order to concatenate content and path, you should use `os.path.join`:

```
bot.upload_photo(os.path.join(content,path), caption ="Technical Scripter Event 2019")
```